# lspci shows wireless network device but network manager doesn't

Tags: wireless, broadcom, sony

The laptop is a Sony Vaio, model number vgn-cr290. I dropped it last night. The hard drive was bad, but I was able to fix that. After about 4 or 5 hours of trying to get wifi to work, I gave up. I have tried re-seating the card, time and time again.

So, messing around on Google, and the prompt, i have found the following things out.

lspci does show the device:

02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev01)

the hardware switch is on, how ever rfkill shows only the bluetooth device

0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no

The network manager shows no wifi device. Why am i getting the contradictions in readings? Is there something i can do in software to fix this?

Also when I try to shutdown my computer, even from the command prompt, the computer seems to halt, but not power down.

Comment: what did you do to fix the hard drive? That may be related.

Comment: replaced it, usually when you have to install the firmware, the network manager tells you thats what you need to do. strange that it is not happening like that this time around.

Answer (score 0):

Always had problems with Broadcom. You need enable kernel module b43, you can do that with this lines of code.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe b43
```

`linux-firmware-nonfree` should contain that module for you.

If you previously did some changes, you may need take them back, especially if you installed something with `-kernel` in it, then unsinstall it with

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ....
```

More info [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2135078&page=2)

Comment: it appears to me that this is not the problem. i also have no blacklisted drivers that call for broadcom